# live change on input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable the next input boxes if the first input box is not empty, using jQuery:

```
<input name = "mrp" id="mrp" type = "text" />
<input name = "miw" class="mmw" type = "text" />
<input name = "maw" class="mmw" type = "text" />
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mrp').blur(function() {     //i have even tried with live('change')
               var mrp = $(this).val();
               if(mrp != '' || mrp != ' '){
                 $('.mmw').attr("disabled", "disabled");   
               }
               else if(mrp == '' || mrp == ' '){
                   $('.mmw').removeAttr("disabled");
               }
               else{
                  $('.mmw').removeAttr("disabled");
               }
        });
});
```

It disables the next input boxes fine, but when I clear the first text box, it doesn't remove the `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to detect when the first input is filled.

This can be done with

```
$(window).ready(function() {  
    var handler = function() {
    if ($('#mrp').val().trim()!='') $('.mmw').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else $('.mmw').removeAttr('disabled');
    };
    $('#mrp').keyup(handler).change(handler);
});​
```

The "lose focus" detections are generally bad because you don't expect to have to click elsewhere to see the other inputs change. That's the reason why I propose to use `keyup'.

EDIT : here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jxgTe/

Comment: its not working as expected, it disable .mmw inputs disable and if i fill the first text box value if removes disable, opposite to requirement

Comment: Sorry, I had understood you wanted the opposite. I Fixed it.

Comment: Just a quick note, your code doesn't account for data being inserted via another function.. see http://jsfiddle.net/Pfek4/ When a function inserts data the `.keyup` is never fired. You need to use more than just keyup

Answer (score 1):

I use `keyup` event for example,  you may use `blur` or `keyup blur` both.

```
$('input[name=mrp]').keyup(function() {
    if ($.trim(this.value).length) {
        $(this).nextAll('input.mmw').prop('disabled', true);
    } else $(this).nextAll('input.mmw').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/78/)**

Comment: thanks for answer, is it necessary to use nextAll('input[name=mrp]'), can we use nextAll('.mmw') instead of this, as our input boxes name are not same.